# Can PHP pages be run locally?

Tags: php, html, forms

Can PHP pages be run locally?

I am trying several demos on creating a contact form, at the moment I am trying this one:

http://www.html-form-guide.com/contact-form/php-email-contact-form.html

I have downloaded the source files and put my own email address in, but when I click submit I get directed to the PHP page. The form's action attribute is set to that PHP page, so I was wondering if it is because PHP is not able to run locally? If I want the form to submit and send to my email would I need to put the downloaded source pages online to make them work?

This is not the only tutorial I've used where this happens.

Sorry if this is a silly question - newbie web developer :).

Thanks.

Comment: what OS u used? you need install a php web server.

Answer (score 2):

PHP, in this context, is a server side language. It must be run by a webserver.

The webserver can be installed and run locally.

Answer (score 1):

PHP needs to be executed server-side, which means you will need to set up a local webserver.

The best way to go would be taking a look at [WAMP](http://www.wampserver.com/en/) or [MAMP](http://www.mamp.info/en/) or LAMP, depending on your operating system.

Comment: At the moment I would not recommend WAMP you mentioned. It's not very actively maintained

Comment: @MarcinNabiałek What are you talking about? That is the most actively maintained version of AMP for windows.

Comment: @Laurent - at the moment yes, there are fresh versions of php on WAMP but about a month ago there weren't and when I tried to switch between php versions and running multiple Apache it simple stopped working and couldn't be fixed and I needed to reinstall it. I used WAMP about 5-6 years (?) and at the moment much better choice is http://www.easyphp.org/ - I have there even phpmyadmin 4.2.0 released on 8th May or PHP 5.6.0beta2 released on 2th May. And there are no problems with switching PHP versions as in WAMP.

Comment: @MarcinNabiałek See [P.E.B.C.A.K.](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/PEBCAK)

Comment: @Ohgodwhy if Wampserver has functionality to change php version and apache and when I simple choose option from menu and it finally stopped working I think that's rather not my fault

Answer (score 1):

You need to be running a PHP server locally, and have the file "hosted" by the server (in the same folder, but usually /var/www/). There are a verity of free programs for this. I like WAMP ( http://sourceforge.net/projects/wampserver/)

Answer (score 1):

You should simple install WAMP server. If you use Windows I recommend this one: http://www.easyphp.org/

When you install it you should copy php file to projects directory and then you can run in your browser `http://localhost/projects/` to see your file and to execute it